# Infinite cyclic group generated by every single element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This probably is a stupid question, but is there an infinite cyclic group generated by every single one of its nonidentity elements?

Comment: If $a$ is a generator of this group, $a^2$ is not a generator since $a$ is not in the subgroup generated by $a^2$.

Comment: Perhaps you mean every non-identity element?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo: that is not generally true, for example in $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @auke But (I think) it is when the group is infinite.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo: then give a proof of that :-/

Comment: If $a=a^{2k}$ for some integer $k$, then $a^{2k-1}=e=a^0$ (identity element). But we have $a^j\neq a^n$ if $j\neq n$ thanks to the infiniteness of the group.

Comment: A cyclic group is generated by any of its non-identity elements if and only if it is cyclic of prime order. This thread covers the infinite case, while if your group is of order $n=ab$ and generated by an element $x$ then $x^a$ has order $b$ in your group so cannot generate the whole group.

Answer (score 13):

The infinite cyclic group is unique up to isomorphism.  If $C$ is infinite cyclic and is generated by $x$ and by $y$, then $x=ky$ and $y=hx$ for some $k,h\in\mathbb Z$.  But then $x=khx$, so $hk=1$ and either $h=k=1$ or $h=k=-1$.  So either $x=y$ or $x=-y$.

Answer (score 11):

Up to isomorphism there is only one infinite cyclic group, the integers under addition; it has only two generators, $1$ and $-1$.

Answer (score 4):

No. The only infinite cyclic group up to isomorphism is $\mathbb{Z}$, which has only two generators.

Answer (score 4):

The only infinite cyclic group is $\mathbb{Z}$. So, no.